# Hide/Show Rows in Table based on click on other rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have table like this

```
Moscow
 Moscow Shop 1
 Moscow Shop 2
 Moscow Shop 3
Kazan
 Kazan Shop 1
 Kazan Shop 2
 Kazan Shop 3
```

What I want is the table to onload open as

```
Moscow
Kazan
```

Then when you click on Moscow

Table should look like

```
Moscow
 Moscow Shop 1
 Moscow Shop 2
 Moscow Shop 3
Kazan
```

Here is my current Mark up

```
<table id="whereToBuyContentTable" class="whereToBuyTable">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="countryRow categoryHeader">
            <td colspan="3" class="">
                <span class="listItemHeader">
                    Moscow
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" style="float: right;"><img width="20"  src="/Resources/Images/sBackTopPic.png"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                    <td width="30"></td>
                    <td>
                        <p><b>ООО ""</b></p>
                        <p class="">Адрес: </p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                        <p class="depth3"></p>
                        <p class="">Web: <a target="_blank" href=""></a></p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        <tr class="countryRow categoryHeader">
            <td colspan="3" class="">
                <span class="listItemHeader">
                    Kazan
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" style="float: right;"><img width="20"  src="/Resources/Images/sBackTopPic.png"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                    <td width="30"></td>
                    <td>
                        <p><b>ООО ""</b></p>
                        <p class="">Адрес: </p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                        <p class="depth3"></p>
                        <p class="">Web: <a target="_blank" href=""></a></p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                    <td width="30"></td>
                    <td>
                        <p><b>ООО ""</b></p>
                        <p class="">Адрес: </p>
                        <p class=""></p>
                        <p class="depth3"></p>
                        <p class="">Web: <a target="_blank" href=""></a></p>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: are you trying to do this with JavaScript or pure CSS?

Comment: I'd like to do it with Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***This fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/KspT6/) should give you a starting point.

**CSS**

```
.spaceUnder{display:none;}
```

**JS**

```
$('tr:not(.spaceUnder)').click(function(){
   $(this).next().toggle()
});
```

**Update** [***Updated Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/KspT6/1/)

```
$('tr:not(.spaceUnder)').click(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil('tr:not(.spaceUnder)').toggle()
});
```

Comment: Aye this works pretty good, just opens and closes the first row under a city though. How I could I open all tr's under the city until I hit a tr with a new city.

Comment: look at .nextUntil() for that. Updated answer

Comment: Aye, that's nice. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to do this. Since these are tables and I assume that since you are using tables, this is dynamic tabular data.

CSS:

```
tr.spaceUnder{display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$("tr.categoryHeader").click(function(){$(this+" + tr.spaceUnder").toggle();});
```

The main trouble you are having -- I think -- is that you need to find a way to select the correct element to show/hide. However, your code does not have any way to specify each code block discretely. The above method (plus others) should be able to do this, or, (easier from the front-end dev perspective) would be to label each of your clickable and toggle-able areas with html, perhaps using id, using the primary key or index from the data fields from the database this is coming from. I assume that this is coming from a database.